# TS require consistent method parameters on sub-classes

Tags: typescript, oop, interface, abstract-class, typescript-types

I declare an abstract class containing a method whose signature specifies a parameter `context: StateMachine`

```
abstract class State {
    abstract enter(context: StateMachine): void
}
```

I expect the TypeScript language server to require sub-classes implementations to also specify a conformant parameter. However, no VSCode IDE warnings show up when the method is implemented without parameters, and `tsc` successfully compiles.

```
class Idle extends State {
    enter(): void { // <-- missing parameter, yet still works
        ...
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of IDE allowing the code with no alerts]

This seems problematic because it allows consumers of a state to attempt to pass a `StateMachine` context - as specified by the interface - to a method which may not be implemented to receive it.

```
class SomeContext extends StateMachine {
    state: State

    constructor(initialState: State) {
        super(initialState)
    }

    update() {
        this.state.enter(this) // <-- state might be Idle, doesn't take a context
    }
}
```

Interestingly, the above code doesn't actually fail on runtime. Still, does this not violate the Liskov Substitution principle?

Is this intended behavior of TS, or a setting that I have misconfigured? Are there scenarios where sub-class method implementations should have different parameters than it's base-class's? Can I fix this if it's faulty?

Comment: It's intended behaviour and consistent with the JS backing – an implementation of a method may choose to ignore trailing (or all) parameters. You would get an error if the subclass method specified an incompatible parameter, or extra parameters.

Comment: @motto I've just tested the code example in my updated post, and it surprisingly did not result in any error. I guess JS just discards the argument? Still, are there any techniques or annotations I can use to ensure that implementers specify certain parameters?

Comment: No? Why would you force implementers to use parameters?

Comment: Does someone (@motto?) want to write up an answer here with a link to [the relevant documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions)?  Imagine how annoying it would be to get an error when writing `[1, 2, 3].map(x => x*x)` and instead have to write `[1, 2, 3].map((x, idx, arr) => x*x)` instead because implementing functions are required to declare parameters they don't care about.

Comment: @pink it seems like there may be scenarios where allowing method implementations to forego and discard parameters specified in the abstract can be deceptive. Consider an abstract method `determineDifficulty(level: Level)`. The signature suggests that difficulty *is a function of* the level itself; that passing different levels may result in different difficulties; that the level is somehow relevant in determining difficulty. Allowing a sub-class to ignore the passed `Level`  and pick a difficulty at random may be misleading to callers or contrary to the philosophical nature of the method.

Comment: if a users implementation would cause unexpected behavior at runtime, you should throw an error or define default behavior

Answer (score 4):

This is the intended behaviour, and it's consistent with the underlying JS implementation.

A subclass's definition of a method must be compatible with the superclass's declaration, according to the [standard Typescript rules for function compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions):

- Each parameter in the subclass method must have a corresponding parameter in the superclass method, with a compatible type (disregarding the names).
- The subclass method's return type must be a subtype of the superclass method's return type.

**That's all**. In particular, there is no requirement for the subclass method to require *every* parameter in the superclass, or in general for a function implementation to make use of every parameter provided to it (cf [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#parameters) / [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) etc).

Parameter types are restrictions placed on the caller, which must provide arguments matching those types. In turn, the return type is a restriction placed on the function implementation – it must return a value matching its return type, and it doesn't matter if that value is ever used by the caller.

Even supposing that the subclass declaration did have to match the superclass declaration, the implementation may just ignore the values of those parameters, or use them trivially.

I would agree with you that if a particular implementation is "misleading to callers or contrary to the philosophical nature of the method" then it's not a very good implementation! Code that doesn't do what the caller expects is either buggy or the wrong piece of software for the task, but these are not perhaps problems that can be addressed in a meaningful way even by exceptionally strong typing.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior in TypeScript. When an abstract class defines a method with parameters, it is only specifying the types of the parameters, not their names. Therefore, derived classes can use different parameter names as long as they have the same types. If you want to ensure that derived classes use the same parameter name as the base class, you should explicitly name the parameters in the abstract class. However, this is not necessary for the TypeScript compiler to validate the implementation of abstract methods.

Comment: they did name the parameters, the question was ever about the names of the parameters but about forcing the parameters to be used