# TypeScript does not show error for missing parameters

Tags: typescript

```
 interface ISave{
   save(path: string, computer: Computer): void;
}

class SaveComputerToFile implements ISave{
    public save(): void{
        console.log(("saving in file"));
    }
}
```

Why doesn't typescript show an error, because in the `SaveComputerToFile` class the save method has no parameters although it should have?

I tried enabling `strictFunctionTypes` in the `tsconfig.json` file and restarted the program but that didn't help either

Comment: Because the method **can still** be called with two parameters of the appropriate types; it's compatible, the interface can't require you to _do anything_ with them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TS require consistent method parameters on sub-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75909112/ts-require-consistent-method-parameters-on-sub-classes)